# Merge URL parameters and generate a encrypted URL - Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-5.3, url-encoding

I have a URL like http://localhost:8000/assessment/3/199

Where 3 represents assignment id and 199 represents assessor id, in short they both represents two models.

I'm sending such URL into email. I want to first encrypt the URL and then send it to the email.

I want URL like http://localhost:8000/assessment/{some-long-random-string}

So, I want to merge both the parameters, make an encrypted string, send into email, upon accessing the URL decrypt it and get both actual parameters.

I would like a solution which uses Laravel to implement that.
May be using these:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/encryption

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing

Comment: Search for packages that do this before asking.

Comment: @Kyslik Actually, I already did, but none of them provides such merge and encrypt technique. So, I thought would be good to create custom one.

Comment: I found this interesting: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php

Answer (score 0):

The way I would tackle this, is by manually implementing it in a controller. 
Generate the URL like this:

```
$url = URL::action('AssessmentController@decrypt', json_encode([
    'assessment' => $assessment_id, 
    'assessor' => $assessor_id
]);
//now, use $url in your email
```

Create a route like:

```
Route::get('/assessment/{ciphertext}', 'AssessmentController@decrypt');
```

In the controller:

```
public function decrypt($ciphertext){

    $params = json_decode(decrypt($ciphertext));
    return $this->getAssessment($params['assessment'], $params['assessor']);

}
```

Of course, you will need more integrity-checks and some error handling, but you probably get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I just don't understand one thing that, the first part of the code, where does it go?